# Transfer function of a state space with correlated noises

Tags: linear-transformations, control-theory, optimal-control

Assume a standard MIMO state-space
\begin{align}
x_{i+1}&= Fx_i + Gw_i\\
y_i&= Hx_i + v_i,
\end{align}
where the sequence $(w_i,v_i)$ is Gaussian i.i.d. with $\mathbb{E}[v_iw_i^T] = L$.

What is the corresponding transfer function?

This takes me to my main question whether we can "approximate" any continuous transfer function with a state-space with uncorrelated noise, i.e., $L=0$.

Comment: Transfer function between what? What are your inputs/outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we disregard the fact that the sequence $(w_i, v_i)$ is Gaussian or correlated.
Then by considering $(w_i, v_i)$ as the input of the State-Space, one could rewrite it to the following:
$$x_{i+1} = Fx_i + \begin{bmatrix}G & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}w_i \\ v_i\end{bmatrix}$$
$$y_{i} = Hx_i + \begin{bmatrix}0 & I\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}w_i \\ v_i\end{bmatrix}$$

Which looks like a regular discrete-time state-space model. Therefore, the corresponding Transfer function would be:
$$P(z) = \frac{Y(z)}{U(z)} = H(zI-F)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}G & 0\end{bmatrix} +  \begin{bmatrix}0 & I\end{bmatrix}$$
$$Y(z) = H(zI-F)^{-1}G W(z) + V(z)$$

Since I am not using any probabilistic properties, the fact that they are correlated is not important. This can however become troublesome if you try to control either $w$ or $v$, as the other one will change as well due to this correlation. With that, I should also note that this is also problematic if you try to identify a system with this structure, then we have to use alternative techniques (depending on what you can measure of course).

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. Given your explanation and the TF formula, is it fair to say that the covariance of any Gaussian random process can be approximated (to an arbitrary precision in some norm) with the covariance of the output of a state-space whose inputs are Gaussian (and are even are uncorrelated).